# My humidifier sets off the breaker?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, humidifier

I live in an apartment with a flatmate, in Ontario, Canada. I have a Honeywell Warm Mist Top Fill Humidifier (HWM-340BC from Canadian Tire, I imagine it should be akin to HWM-340B here: https://www.honeywellstore.com/store/products/easy-to-care-warm-mist-humidifier-hwm-340b.htm) and I use it because I have breathing difficulty at low humidity. However, it occasionally trips the breaker, and the breaker controls all the electric sockets in both bedrooms, which is not acceptable because my roommate does his work on a desktop computer.

Last time I brought this up with maintenance, and the guy basically said "Plug it into one of the other circuits" because apparently the bedroom circuits are all controlled by an arc-fault circuit (as mandated in new apartments by Canadian building guidelines)? I have to flick the breaker to reset it, and the breaker has a TEST button on it. The other breakers have stickers on them that say Schneider so I'm inclined to believe this one is made by Schneider as well.

Is there an easy fix wherein I can use my humidifier? I.e. a power surge power bar or something?

Comment: Does it trip an ordinary breaker - i.e., you have flip the breaker to reset, or is it a GFCI or AFCI - push a little reset button?

Comment: When it trips off the breaker, it stops working.  **What else stops working?** List everything.

Comment: Does the breaker in question have a TEST button on it? What make and model is this humidifier?

Comment: @manassehkatz I do have to flick the breaker to reset. However, the maintenance guy I talked to said it was an arc-fault, I believe (and they're mandatory in all new apartments here). There's a little "Test" button on it too.

Comment: @Harper I mean the breaker flicks off, so everything connected turns off, including laptop charger, monitor, a TV, a desktop computer, the humidifier. I have to manually flick the breaker back and then things work again.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, it does. I think it's an arc-fault. Would a photo be useful? The humidifier is HWM-340BC from Canadian Tire (probably the same as the HWM-340B here: https://www.honeywellstore.com/store/products/easy-to-care-warm-mist-humidifier-hwm-340b.htm )

Comment: @personjerry -- what make and model is said breaker?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I don't know, and I don't know how to remove it to find out. The flicking thing says 15 on it, and the electric panel is made by Schneider so I guess it's a 15A arc fault breaker by Schneider Electric

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The entire thing is black except the TEST button which is white.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Based on the text on the electric panel (Square D) and the look and color of the breaker, I've made an educated guess that it's one of these two (almost identical) products: https://www.se.com/us/en/product/HOM115PCAFI/miniature-circuit-breaker-120v-15a/?range=7228-square-d%E2%84%A2-homeline%E2%84%A2-miniature-circuit-breakers&node=12144458657-(cafi)-combo-arc-fault-breakers https://www.se.com/us/en/product/HOM115PCAFIC/miniature-circuit-breaker-120v-15a/?range=7228-square-d%E2%84%A2-homeline%E2%84%A2-miniature-circuit-breakers&node=12144458657-(cafi)-combo-arc-fault-breakers

Comment: For reference, the humidifier is listed as 400W, so nothing too bad, but that's still 20% of the rated amperage on the circuit.

Comment: @personjerry do you have a stopwatch handy?

Comment: The humidifier is a small load but everything plugged into that circuit adds up, either you are overloading the circuit or their is a fault. The 3rd possibility is the type of humidifier ultrasonic ones may be causing harmonics on the power that the at fault breaker thinks are faults (this is an issue with computer power supplies, modern discharge lighting, and led lighting circuits when AFCI’s are involved.

Comment: This appears to be a steam type of humidifier, not ultrasonic; basically an electric kettle. So it's likely the COMBINATION of your flatmate's PC plus the humidifier LOAD that is exceeding the rating of the breaker, not that it is an AFCI. AFCIs are known to have issues with harmonics and some types of motors, but typically a boiler type of device is as clean and simple of an electrical load as you can find. Unless there is something wrong with it... So given that's only a 400W load, the problem is more likely that his PC and appurtenances are running right at the ragged edge of the rating.

Comment: @JRaef -- could very well be, although most PCs don't come close to pushing the limits of a 15A circuit, either.  I do want him to try the trip diagnostics procedure for his breaker though....